# How to print the php variable value when working in ajax

Tags: php

In the following php code executes on ajax call but i want to check $cart_final variables value but its not getting printed though i have used die function. Please suggest me any solutions.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item']) && $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item']['meal_dish_type']==$meal_dish_type)
{
      $item[]=array('meal_type'=>$meal_type,'meal_package'=>$meal_package,'meal_time'=>$meal_time,'meal_plan_days'=>$meal_plan_days,'meal_dish_type'=>$meal_dish_type,'prefixed_qty'=>$prefixed_qty,'prefixed_date'=>$prefixed_date,'cart_plan'=>$cart_total,'product_rule'=>$product_rule,'prefixed_date_item'=>$prefixed_date_item);

       //$dish=array_push($dish,$item);
     $cart_final = array_merge($_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'], $item);

        print_r($cart_final); die;// i want to print this value
       $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'] = $cart_final;

       //$_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'] = $dish;
       $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['cart_total'] =  $cart_total*$prefixed_qty;


}
```

Comment: If `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item']` is not `array` - results can be unexpected.

Comment: yes its array...here i want to check the inserting value in this 
$_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item']    u_mulder Do you know any solution

Comment: Hello are you there

Answer (score 0):

You can see your `ajax` output in Developer Tools, Network. File and its output will be shown after ajax call. You will see name of your php file called by ajax and its details. I use this way, because I can check variables and also I can see warnings, errors or notices.

[image: Developer tools, network]

Comment: i want to stop php script execution and display variable value....am not getting any value in ajax

Comment: @Hemant I don't understand. If you want to debug, you can print any variable in php script called by ajax this way. If you want you display variable in html, you will need to echo your data back to ajax function and than display received data to html.